# Target first level <li> by using LESS nested rules with BEM

Tags: html, css, less, bem

I have the following HTML:

```
<ul class="header-menu">
    <li class="header-menu__item"><a href="index.html">home</a></li>
    <li class="header-menu__item header-menu__item--split"><a href="menu.html">menu</a></li>
    <li class="header-menu__item">
        <a href="#">features</a>
        <ul class="header-menu--dropdown">
            <li><a href="menu.html">Menu</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>    <!-- end header-menu -->
```

I have this css, is it possible to do something like this in less:

```
.header-menu{}
    .header-menu .header-menu__item{}
    .header-menu > .header-menu__item{}
```

I would write it in LESS with BEM like this:

```
.header-menu{
    &__item{
        display: inline-block;
        float: left;
    }

    > &__item{ // How can I target first <li>(s) here
    }
}
```

How can I apply a CSS rule to the first `<li>` level? Tried `> &__item` but it doesn't seem to work.

**Updated:** Fixed by myself. I missed `&` in front of `> &__item`

```
.header-menu{
    &__item{
        display: inline-block;
        float: left;
    }

    & > &__item{ <--- I miss '&' here
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me how apply with BEM?

Answer (score 1):

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/s191e6qp/

targeted `<a>` tag

```
.header-menu {
    > li a {
      color:red; /* first level */
    }
    li li a {
      color:green; /* second level */
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I'm using BEM with LESS so can you tell me how to apply this with these syntax.

Answer (score 0):

It has to be something like this:

```
.header-menu{
    &__item{
        display: inline-block;
        float: left;
    }

    > &__item:first{ /* :first will let you select only first li */
    }
}
```

or

```
.header-menu{
    &__item{
        display: inline-block;
        float: left;
    }

    > li:first{ 
          /* :first will let you select only first li */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to clarify:

HTML:

```
<ul class="header-menu">
    <li class="header-menu__item">First level item (first item in this level)</li>
    <li class="header-menu__item">
        First level item
        <ul>
            <li class="header-menu__item">Second level item</li> 
            <li class="header-menu__item">Second level item</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="header-menu__item">First level item</li>
</ul>
```

LESS-CSS:

```
.header-menu{
    &__item{
        color: red;
    }

    & > &__item{
        color: green;

        &:first-child{
            color: grey;    
        }
    }
}
```

you can look at this example to see how it works